# How to Resolve 404 error using org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.postForObject(). With valid Parameters and URI

Tags: java, spring, maven, http-status-code-404, webservice-client

When using org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.client.WebClient the url works and connects, so I know my parameters and my emailServiceURI are not the problem. But when using import org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate, I get this exception. I'm using this code in the IDE.

```
RestTemplate template = new RestTemplate();
template.postForObject(emailServiceURI,params,ParametersFromFilenet.class);
```

-

```
404 Not Found
org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException: 404 Not Found
    at org.springframework.web.client.DefaultResponseErrorHandler.handleError(DefaultResponseErrorHandler.java:88)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.handleResponseError(RestTemplate.java:537)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:493)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:452)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.postForObject(RestTemplate.java:302)
    at com.phx.filenet.FilenetDelegator.sendToWebService(FilenetDelegator.java:107)
    at com.phx.filenet.FilenetDelegator.main(FilenetDelegator.java:46)
```

Ultimately I want to create a jar that will call a web service with parameters from a jar.

I ran into problems including a jace.jar with maven and resolved that, a problem getting the right jars for springframework.web.client and resolved that, a problem kicking it off from command line and resolved that. This is the latest challenge I faced so I am bringing it to the community.

Comment: I know you say that the URI is not the problem, but a 404 error implies that the URI is the problem.  Have you inspected your request externally to be sure that it is being made to the correct URL?

Comment: Yes, I hit it with the browser and it worked fine. In fact I executed the code using a different web client and it also worked fine.